# How to change two different .css class values with select option?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, layout

I have a small problem. My idea is to have option to change values in two different .css class with

```
<select>
  <option value="one">Orange/Blue<option>
  <option value="two">example1/example1<option>
  <option value="three">example2/example2<option>
<select>
```

How should I deal with that kind of situation? I will add some pictures below so you can understand me a little bit more.

[Current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIYpJ.png)

So if I select the second option and I will get the color option different. Also i have the `<hr>` on first `.css` class and and the `Some random text` & `Blue examples` on the other `.css` class.
I hope you all understood what I meant to say!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is app.js file

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [select, setSelect] = useState("blue");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <hr />
      <h2 className={select === "blue" ? "blue" : "orange"}>
        Some random text!
      </h2>

      <select defaultValue={"blue"} onChange={e => setSelect(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="orange">Orange</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and this is style.css

```
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
.orange {
  color: orange;
}
```

this is link https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-thunder-zwrc8
you can check live